# Why does Spring boot not support jsp while it can render the page if we add proper jar reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

It is written everywhere that Spring boot does not support jsp view. In its official document there are three reasons

> - With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. An executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also
>     be deployable to any standard container. JSPs are not supported when
>     using an executable jar.
> - Undertow does not support JSPs.
> - Creating a custom error.jsp page does not override the default view for error handling. Custom error pages should be used instead.

For the first item, 'JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar'. But when I add reference to tomcat-embed-jasper and set correct resource path in application.properties, the jsp file can also be rendered well.

I guess this may mean that Spring boot not support jsp without invovling other reference libs such as tomcat-embed-jasper.

But for thymleaf, we also have to import spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf. Why can we say that Spring boot support thymleaf with involving extra libs.

So how can I understand the first item in document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Embedded Tomcat package (which is used in springboot to create executable jar)does not include JSP by default, we must add the module `“org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper”` as well.That is the reason why we are adding `tomcat-embed-jasper` as dependency in springboot, so that we can use the jstl tags in jsp.

The main reason why springboot does not work properly with jsp as view resolver , when `*jar` is used as packaging is because of **a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat**.The issue is that when you are using `java -*.jar` to deploy a springboot application , the jsp files will not be present in the embedded tomcat and while trying to serve the request you will get a **404 PAGE NOT FOUND**. This is because of the jar packaging ,that the jsp files are not getting copied from the `WEB-INF` folder.If you keep the jsp files under the `META-INF/resources` folder while using jar as packaging it should work.

Thymeleaf allows using templates as prototypes, meaning they can be viewed as static files and put in `resources/templates` folder for spring to pick up.But jsp files will have jstl tags etc which needs to be transpiled by the jasper before rendering , so they cannot be set as static files according to my knowledge.

When using a **WAR**(Webapplication archive), the packing will automatically take the resources from the following project structure :

```
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.jsp
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

Guides and official sample for using springboot with jsp : [Guide](https://htr3n.github.io/2018/12/jsp-spring-boot/) , [Sample Repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src)

The WAR packaging structure insists on keeping jsp files under `webapp/` folder and it will work as expected. The maven war goal will copy the files from the webapp folder to the `WEB-INF` and all resource files like jsp will  be at the root of the war packaging.From here, the maven-repackage goal or spring boot repackaging takes care of making the jar/war executable.So, if the files are present in the orginal war , it will be in the executable one as well.The **springboot executable war structure** is as follows :

> ```
> example.war
>  |
>  +-META-INF
>  |  +-MANIFEST.MF
>  +-org
>  |  +-springframework
>  |     +-boot
>  |        +-loader
>  |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
>  +-WEB-INF
>     +-classes
>     |  +-com
>     |     +-mycompany
>     |        +-project
>     |           +-YourClasses.class
>     +-lib
>     |  +-dependency1.jar
>     |  +-dependency2.jar
>     +-lib-provided
>        +-servlet-api.jar
>        +-dependency3.jar
> ```

So for the comment :

If you put your jsp files in the folder `src/main/resources` , anything that is put in this directory will be automatically copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` as per the **WAR** [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

So , if you keep your jsp files under src/main/resources and configure the following in yml or property file, it should work for WAR archives.I haven't tried it so not sure.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/classes/templates
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

Comment: OK. That explains why jar package not work while war package does not for spring boot application.

Comment: @RobinSun This is as per my knowledge and from my experience in working with the upgrade of a legacy application .Happy to be of help.

Comment: Hi @Ananthapadmanabhan, thanks for your help. Still one question here, if we use jsp files, we should keep it under the META-INF/resources folder. Why we don't put it just in the root resources folder(which will be put in the top folder structure in jar file after packaging)? Is there any connection between META-INF/resources and a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat?

Comment: The issue is actually tomcat expects the resources to follow one particular folder structure but when using the jar packaging maven or other build tools may not copy the resources files from the webapps folder, they just ignore it for some reason unknown to me, but will copy resources from META-INF folder, that is why it works. When using war, it expects the project structure to be as i provided.Your suggesstion of putting jsp under main resources might work , i have not tried that.

Comment: @RobinSun I have udpated the answer with more details and links.if you are satisfied with my answer please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Robin Sun,

I added in pom `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper` and compiled `.war` and my docker images could recognise my jsps

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use JSP. As it turns out, Java servlet containers—including embedded Tomcat and Jetty containers—usually look for JSPs somewhere under /WEB-INF. But if you’re building your application as an executable JAR
file, there’s no way to satisfy that requirement. Therefore, JSP is only an option if
you’re building your application as a WAR file and deploying it in a traditional servlet
container. If you’re building an executable JAR file, you must choose Thymeleaf,
FreeMarker, or one of the other options

Comment: Are you sure? there must be a way for jsp also