# Spring Boot Index jsp works on localhost, but not found in linux server

Tags: linux, spring, maven, spring-boot, jsp

I create Spring Boot application. It works successfully in my localhost.
But when I deploy and run jar file in linux centos server index page can not found 
(I get : There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp)

This is my code structure and application.properties :

[code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xzKH.png)

and here is my pom.xml dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I inserted <packaging>war</packaging> to pom.xml and it solved problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springboot and jsp **does not work properly with jar packaging** due to a hardcoded pattern in tomcat. So, it's *preferable to use* **war** packaging along with springboot if you are using jsp as view render and deploying in tomcat.

The issue is that when you are using `jar` to deploy a springboot application , the jsp files will not be present in the tomcat and while trying to serve the request you will get a **404 PAGE NOT FOUND**. This is because of the jar packaging ,that the jsp files are not getting copied from the WEB-INF folder.If you keep the jsp files under the `META-INF/resources` folder while using jar as packaging it should work.But springboot documentation itself makes it clear that it is preferable to use **war** as packaging along with jsp.

> With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. An
>   executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also
>   be deployable to any standard container. JSPs are not supported when
>   using an executable jar.

Spring [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Related Post : [Why does Spring boot not support jsp while it can render the page if we add proper jar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537151/why-does-spring-boot-not-support-jsp-while-it-can-render-the-page-if-we-add-prop/56537463#56537463)