# Spring Boot controller redirect to /template jsp page NOT WORKING

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to redirect from a very simple controller to a jsp page that is located in resources/templates, but I don't want to use ViewResolver java configuration, instead I want to use application properties prefix and suffix!

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String redirectToMainPage() {
        return "main-page";
    }
```

and these are my application properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

the jsp location is:

```
/src/main/resources/templates/main-page.jsp
```

But i always get this error:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Nov 13 13:38:55 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

EDIT: I just created the project from Spring initializr. Below is the important bits, the others are just autogenerated dependendecies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>web.site</groupId>
    <artifactId>cookBook</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cookBook</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging> 

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you using jar as packaging ? If so change it to war as springboot does not work properly with jar and jsp as view. Also , please share your pom and directory structure as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have updated the packaging to war but i still get the same error. I also posted the the structure of the pom!

Comment: Please post the whole content of pom.xml.

Comment: Okay, i did update it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The embedded jasper dependency is needed to render the jsp files. Also, change your packaging to `war` when you are using `jsp` as view renderer.

Comment: I accept this as the correct answer, it's working! Can you give me a bit of an explanation as to why it is working :D

Comment: @AlexVulchev please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537151/why-does-spring-boot-not-support-jsp-while-it-can-render-the-page-if-we-add-prop/56537463#56537463