# Spring Boot : Whitelabel Error Page with 404 status code

Tags: spring-boot

I have developed small spring boot application with jar packaging. The application use case is, user will login into application and it will display welcome page. Below is my code.

Main class

```
package com.ibm.heathcare;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.ibm.heathcare.*"})
public class HeathcareappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HeathcareappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Login controller class

```
package com.ibm.heathcare.controller;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.ibm.heathcare.modal.Login;
import com.ibm.heathcare.modal.User;
import com.ibm.heathcare.service.AuthService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"userName","uid"})
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
        //model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
        return "login";
    }
    
    
      @RequestMapping("/logout") 
      public String showLogoutPage(ModelMap model){
      model.put("message", "Successfully Log out...");
      return "redirect:/login"; 
      
      }
      @RequestMapping("/welcome")
      public String showWelcomePage(ModelMap model) {
          return "welcome";
      }
     
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showwelcomePage(@RequestParam String uid, @RequestParam String pwd,ModelMap model){
        Optional<User> optUser=authService.getAuthenticate(uid, pwd);
        if(optUser.isPresent()) {
            User user=optUser.get();
            model.put("userName", user.getUserName() );
            model.put("uid", user.getUserId());
            return "welcome";
        }else {
            model.addAttribute("login", new Login("",""));
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage",new String("Invalid Credential"));
            
            return "login";
        }
        
    }

}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
            User ID :<input type="text" name="uid"/><p>
            Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file="common/navigation.jspf" %>
<div class="jumbotron text-center" >
    <h1>Welcome<h1><p>
    <h2> ${userName} </h2>
</div>
<%@ include file="common/footer.jspf" %>
```

application.properties

```
#Server Configuration
server.port = 8282

#ViwResolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>heathcare</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>heathcareapp</name>
    <description>Health Care Management Application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Now when I have executed this application through eclipse it was working fine.
I have built a jar of application using maven tool which created in target folder. I have executed the application jar from target folder using command line. It worked fine. But when I copy same jar to another folder on my machine and try to execute using java -jar app.jar command and hit the url http://localhost:8282/login in browser it gives me **Whitelabel Error Page with status code 404.**  I am not sure what is wrong with the application. I have searched lot on web and some experts suggested to explicitly write @ComponentScan with basepackage information in main class. I did same but it was not worked for me.
In console I am getting below log.

```
2020-07-10 10:38:52.605  INFO 11788 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-10 10:38:53.888  INFO 11788 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-07-10 10:38:53.918  INFO 11788 --- [           main] c.ibm.heathcare.HeathcareappApplication  : Started HeathcareappApplication in 24.424 seconds (JVM running for 25.755)
2020-07-10 10:39:18.728  INFO 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-10 10:39:18.729  INFO 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-10 10:39:18.730 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-07-10 10:39:18.783 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-07-10 10:39:18.784  INFO 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 54 ms
2020-07-10 10:39:18.901 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2020-07-10 10:39:18.916 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ibm.heathcare.controller.LoginController#showLoginPage(ModelMap)
2020-07-10 10:39:19.022 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-07-10 10:39:19.022 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'login', model {}
2020-07-10 10:39:19.043 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2020-07-10 10:39:19.160 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-07-10 10:39:19.163 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2020-07-10 10:39:19.168 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-07-10 10:39:19.664 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-07-10 10:39:19.684 DEBUG 11788 --- [nio-8282-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Please help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are trying to serve `jsp`  views using jar. It is provided in the spring-boot documentation itself that `jsp` **does not** go well with jar packaging. So, change packaging from jar to `war` . Then , ensure that the jsp files are placed under the `WEB-INF` like you provided in the `application.properties`. Most probably your issue is that the jsp was not included in the jar since it was in the `WEB-INF` folder.

The issue is that when you are using `java -*.jar` to deploy a springboot application , the jsp files will not be present in the embedded tomcat and while trying to serve the request you will get a `404 PAGE NOT FOUND`. This is because of the jar packaging ,that the jsp files are not getting copied from the `WEB-INF` folder.If you keep the jsp files under the `META-INF/resources` folder while using `jar` as packaging it should work.

Related : [Why does Spring boot not support jsp while it can render the page if we add proper jar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537151/why-does-spring-boot-not-support-jsp-while-it-can-render-the-page-if-we-add-prop/56537463#56537463)