# Spring boot docker container returns a file instead of jsp view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a simple dockerized spring boot aplication.
When I run app locally (no docker) everything runs ok. Controllors return jsp views.

but when i run the app using container it is returning me a file which contains html code.
I could try forcing the controller to return html response instead of octet-stream but its not a smart solution.

I realize the issue is somewhere between jasper, tomcat, docker communication but i cant find it out, and i tried a bunch of solution.

Any help is appreciated,

here is my configuration

Thanks

**project structure**

```
├── main/
│   ├── java/
│   │   └── com/
│   │       └── example/
│   │           └── jsp/
│   │               ├── configuration/
│   │               │   └── MvcConfiguration.java
│   │               ├── controller/
│   │               │   ├── IndexController.java
│   │               │   └── ProductController.java
│   │               ├── JspApplication.java
│   │               ├── model/
│   │               │   ├── Author.java
│   │               │   ├── ProductCategory.java
│   │               │   └── Product.java*
│   │               ├── service/
│   │               │   ├── ProductServiceImpl.java
│   │               │   └── ProductService.java*
│   │               └── test/
│   │                   └── CustomClass.java
│   └── resources/
│       ├── application.properties
│       └── META-INF/
│           └── resources/
│               └── index.jsp
└── test/
    └── java/
        └── com/
            └── example/
                └── jsp/
                    └── JspApplicationTests.java
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.com=DEBUG

server.port=8080
spring.rabbitmq.host=
```

**MvcConfiguration.java**

```
package com.example.jsp.configuration;

import com.example.rabbit.client.pageview.PageViewService;
import com.example.rabbit.client.pageview.PageViewServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public PageViewService pageViewService(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return new PageViewServiceImpl(template);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>eps</docker.image.prefix>
        <docker.image.name>pageview_controller</docker.image.name>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>required</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.rabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.20.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>

                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/target/dockerfile</dockerFileDir>

                                <!--copies artficact to docker build dir in target-->
                                <assembly>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>latest</tag>
                                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                </tags>
                            </build>
                            <run>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>8080:8080</port>
                                </ports>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.jsp.test.CustomClass</mainClass>
                    <arguments>${project.name},${project.version}</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**IndexController.java**

```
package com.example.jsp.controller;

import com.example.jsp.service.ProductService;
import com.example.rabbit.client.pageview.PageViewService;
import guru.springframework.model.events.PageViewEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    private ProductService productService;
    private PageViewService pageViewService;;

    @Autowired
    public IndexController(ProductService productService,
                            PageViewService pageViewService
    ) {

        this.productService = productService;
        this.pageViewService = pageViewService;

    }

    @GetMapping({"/", "index"})
    public ModelAndView getIndex(ModelAndView model){

        model.addObject("products", productService.listProducts());

        //Send Page view event
        PageViewEvent pageViewEvent = new PageViewEvent();
        pageViewEvent.setPageUrl("/");
        pageViewEvent.setPageViewDate(new Date());
        pageViewEvent.setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        log.info("Sending Message to pagie view service");
        pageViewService.sendPageViewEvent(pageViewEvent);

        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
    }

}
```

I am using fabric8 to automatically build my image. During building stage CustomClass is creating a Dockerfile based on the following template.

```
FROM openjdk
VOLUME /tmp
ADD maven/${fileName}.jar ${fileName}.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /${fileName}.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/${fileName}.jar"]
```

CustomClass is just a dumb file reader/writer class which creates dynamicly Dockerfile based on the variables from pomx.ml

**CustomClass**

```
public class CustomClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String projectName = args[0];
        String version = args[1];

        File file = new File("development/DockerfileTemplate");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        String content = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\$\\{fileName\\}", projectName+ "-" + version);

        File saveFile = new File("target/dockerfile/Dockerfile");
        saveFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFile);
        fw.write(content);
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

I noticed in logs a difference, dont know if that is related

when using docker, app is redirecting and responding with a file

```
2020-09-20 04:47:10.392 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [index.jsp]
2020-09-20 04:47:10.392 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/index.jsp", parameters={}
2020-09-20 04:47:10.395 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-09-20 04:47:10.396 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 304
2020-09-20 04:47:10.396 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-09-20 04:47:10.396 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED
```

when running app locally, there are no redirects

```
2020-09-20 07:47:54.461 DEBUG 1883 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [index.jsp]
2020-09-20 07:47:54.461 DEBUG 1883 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-09-20 07:47:54.461 DEBUG 1883 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Comment: can you post your main class `com.example.jsp.test.CustomClass` and your project structure as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding - 
I edited the question, added project structure and DockerfileTemplate.

About CustomClass, that is just a dumb file reader/writer class which reads DockerfileTemplate and updates its variables based on the pom.xml variables. This dockerfile is then used to build the image.
I tried using latest openjdk and openjdk:8u181-jdk as a starting point for the image but i get same error

Comment: can you check what is the `content-type` header value returned in GET response?, you can check in browser console.

Comment: content-type is `application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8`. I tried setting `@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)` but i get same effect

Comment: Seems, the `content-type` header is not sent from server, also do you notice the redirect request on browser console also?

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking the same thing. I tried setting `response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE);` but same stuff. There no redirect request in browser console

Comment: can you add small reproducible code to git or something so that I can check locally?

Comment: just run `mvn clean package docker:build` It will create an image. And just run image `docker run -p 8085:8085 test/dockertest`

Comment: I have never used JSP with  spring but will give it a try and see if I can help.

Comment: it didn't work for me as well, apparently seems some issue when jsp used in fat jar, lots of people have issues with this, although spring has mentioned in their docs about limited support for JSP [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) and not sure if it can be run using jar file, tried with war also but same error. so I guess its better you use something else i.e thymleaf

Comment: Thank you a lot for trying. I got to the same conclusion. Jsp has issues when put into docker. it must be deployed as war. I tried a bunch more solutions - i can get it to work locally and I can get it to work in docker using apache image. But those two setups are using different configuration. Main difference in those configuration was presence of jasper dependency. Still thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, serving JSP has some limitations when deployed in a docker. Here is some interesting info on that which helped me finding the solution [Why does Spring boot not support jsp while it can render the page if we add proper jar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537151/why-does-spring-boot-not-support-jsp-while-it-can-render-the-page-if-we-add-prop)

Here is the solution. Its is using apache for serving pages

**Dockerfile template**

```
From tomcat
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY maven/${fileName}.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

**project structure**

```
├── main/
│   ├── java/
│   │   └── com/
│   │       └── example/
│   │           └── jsp/
│   │               ├── configuration/
│   │               │   └── BeanConfiguration.java
│   │               ├── controller/
│   │               │   └── IndexController.java
│   │               ├── converter/
│   │               │   ├── ProductFormToProduct.java*
│   │               │   └── ProductToProductForm.java*
│   │               ├── dto/
│   │               │   └── ProductForm.java
│   │               ├── JspApplication.java
│   │               ├── model/
│   │               │   └── Product.java
│   │               ├── repository/
│   │               │   └── ProductRepository.java
│   │               ├── service/
│   │               │   └── ProductService.java
│   │               ├── test/
│   │               │   └── CustomClass.java
│   │               └── utility/
│   │                   └── HtmlFormatter.java
│   ├── resources/
│   │   ├── application.properties
│   │   └── META-INF/
│   └── webapp/
│       ├── assets/
│       │   ├── css/
│       │   │   └── main.css
│       │   └── js/
│       │       └── script.js
│       └── WEB-INF/
│           └── view/
│               ├── fragments/
│               │   └── nav.jsp
│               └── product/
│                   ├── list.jsp
│                   ├── productform.jsp
│                   └── show.jsp
└── test/
    └── java/
        └── com/
            └── example/
                └── jsp/
                    └── JspApplicationTests.java
```

**Main Spring boot application class**

```
package com.example.jsp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JspApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(JspApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.name>jsp</project.name>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>test</docker.image.prefix>
        <docker.image.name>dockertest</docker.image.name>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--WEBJARS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <WAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</WAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.20.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <!--<dockerHost>http://127.0.0.1:2375</dockerHost>-->
                    <dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>

                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/target/dockerfile</dockerFileDir>

                                <!--copies artficact to docker build dir in target-->
                                <assembly>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>latest</tag>
                                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                </tags>
                            </build>
                            <run>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>8080:8080</port>
                                </ports>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.jsp.test.DockerFileBulder</mainClass>
                    <arguments>${project.name},${project.version}</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**DockerFileBulder**

```
        String projectName = args[0];
        String version = args[1];

        File file = new File("development/DockerfileTemplate");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        String content = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\$\\{fileName\\}", projectName+ "-" + version);

        File saveFile = new File("target/dockerfile/Dockerfile");
        saveFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFile);
        fw.write(content);
        fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the ***IndexController.java***

```
@GetMapping({"/", "index"})
public ModelAndView getIndex(ModelAndView model){

    model.addObject("products", productService.listProducts());

    //Send Page view event
    PageViewEvent pageViewEvent = new PageViewEvent();
    pageViewEvent.setPageUrl("/");
    pageViewEvent.setPageViewDate(new Date());
    pageViewEvent.setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    log.info("Sending Message to pagie view service");
    pageViewService.sendPageViewEvent(pageViewEvent);

    return new ModelAndView("index", model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried that solution but didnt help. 
Anyway in the end i managed to find a solution. The issue is related to serving jsp pages from inside the docker. It is a known issues as it turns out