# Java Spring boot executable JAR file not running into another machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

I am trying to package a Java spring boot (Maven) project into JAR file. So that I can take that JAR file into another computer and simply run it. The file is created inside "target" folder. I can run the project fine with following:

```
java -jar target/project.jar
```

but whenever I take the Jar file to another place (like, into another PC) and try to run like this:

```
java -jar project.jar
```

it's showing *White Label Error 404 page* at - **localhost:8080**

How to package the project to run as standalone JAR file without any such errors?

Here's my **application.properties** file content:

```html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sample
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB

## File Storage Properties
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=/Users/noticepush/notices

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

And this is my **pom.xml** content:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tech</groupId>
    <artifactId>StressDetection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>StressDetection</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
   <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
   <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
   <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestion for me?
Note: Please don't suggest WAR packaging. I am trying to distribute the project as JAR package.

Comment: What about the MariaDB instance you are using? The database can not be packed into Java so you always have an external dependency...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you use java -*.jar to deploy any springboot application , the jsp files will not be present in the embedded tomcat and while trying to serve the request you will get a 404 PAGE NOT FOUND. This is because of the jar packaging ,that the jsp files are not getting copied from the WEB-INF folder. If you keep the jsp files under the META-INF/resources folder while using jar as packaging it should work.

Related Question : [Why does Spring boot not support jsp while it can render the page if we add proper jar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537151/why-does-spring-boot-not-support-jsp-while-it-can-render-the-page-if-we-add-prop/56537463#56537463)

Comment: So keeping jsp files in META-INF/resources folder and building the JAR again will work? I can run the JAR to another machine?

Comment: Where is the META-INF/resources folder? I got no META-INF folder inside resources, only a folder called static which contains images, content and scripts folders.

Answer (score 1):

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sample` Your application has a dependency in some local database.

It can be that in your computer the database exists and is reachable by the application so the application can start and play correctly.

On other computers the database may not exist or may not be reachable from the application so Spring context fails during initialization and therefore the web application is not reachable from you!

If as pointed in comments this is not the issue, then there can be another issue as well.

You can replace the following in your `pom.xml`

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

with

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So that the final Jar is a repackaged Fat jar which will contain also all runtime dependencies needed.

Comment: I also have same DB in another machine, issue is with displaying the page properly

Comment: @AbhiD. please check edited answer

Comment: I did as you suggested, replaced those lines in pom.xml, got fat jar. But still same problem. Showing White Label Error Page whenever I am trying to run the JAR file by taking it outside the target folder.

Comment: @AbhiD. what do the logs say about that?

Comment: here is my log trace - https://textbin.net/bvipjzifxc

Answer (score 0):

I get such error in the past
You are having this error because there is no defaut webPage for spring boot Screenshot with the error

To fix it , you just need to add a simple html file (`index.html`) in you `src/main/resources/statics directory`

Answer (score 0):

You might have to configure a view resolver in this case. Typically we place JSP files in the ${project.basedir}/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/. In such a case, you will have to add following 2 configuration parameters in application.properties.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: Those lines already there in application.properties, check my Post

Comment: Okay. One small question. Is your logic validates "file.upload-dir" location at the time of starting up? Could you please get a log trace here?

Comment: here is my log trace - https://textbin.net/bvipjzifxc

Comment: Checked it, but no strange traces and no clue found.